# how to extract data from a site in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a specific data from a site and paste to a worksheet to update daily a database. But as it is impossible download the table as excel or csv, i should to extract the table directly from the site.

follow my code and where i am with problem (where there is "HERE").

```
Sub Scrape_Stats()

    'Create Internet Explorer Browser
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    'Ask Browser to navigate to website (.Visible=False will hide IE when running)
    With appIE
        .Navigate "https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/ferramentas/contratos-di-futuro"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    'Have the macro pause while IE is busy opening and navigating
    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Designate the table to be extracted and Copy the data from table - HERE



    'Close IE and clear memory
    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing

    'Clear area and paste extracted text into the appropriate sheet/cells - HERE
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:H1000").ClearContents
    Sheets("PPG").Select
    Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I cannot extract the data from a site and paste at my excel. So, the steps "Designate the table to be extracted and Copy the data from table - HERE' " and "'Clear area and paste extracted text into the appropriate sheet/cells - HERE" are not complet

Comment: You don't have any code here that extracts data from a website. It just navigates to the website, lets it load, then you close it. What is your expected outcome?

Comment: I do not know the correct code to extract data from a site, so I left the spaces blank. (I tried a lot of other examples)

Comment: do you have any idea of code that do this funciton?

Comment: Can you post some of the examples so we can see what's not worked and suggest how to make it work, or remove this option from our attempts.  It looks like there is no use of the web page's controls at all in the code, objects to hold them or referencing them

Comment: This is not a coding service where you state your requirements and get back ready-to-run debugged code. 
You need to put in some efforts yourself. Show us your code and also read this:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: You can try to refer these links to get an idea about how to extract data from website to Excel. (1) https://officetricks.com/extract-data-from-website-to-excel-vba/ (2) https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/scraping-web-page-data-automatically-with-excel-vba/ (3) https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/query-table.htm (4) https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm

Comment: Have you tried the solutions given?

Answer (score 3):

Something like should work, I'm using the clipboard to move the data in the table over in one go.

```
Sub Scrape_Stats()
    Dim Clip As Object: Set Clip = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Dim Text As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        .Navigate "https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/ferramentas/contratos-di-futuro"
         Do While .Busy And .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
         Text = .Document.getElementsByTagName("Table")(1).outerhtml
        .Quit
    End With

    Clip.SetText Text
    Clip.PutInClipboard

    ws.Range("A2:H1000").ClearContents
    ws.Range("A2").Select
    ws.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
    Set Clip = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

It is much faster to issue an xmlhtttp request without opening a browser and parse the json hidden in one of the attributes (`data-DIContracts`) of the response.

I use jsonconverter.bas which you can download from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). Once you add the .bas to your project go to vbe > tools > references and add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and one for `Microsoft HTML Object Library`.

The line

```
.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
```

is to guard against being served cached results given the frequent page updates.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, json As Object, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/ferramentas/contratos-di-futuro", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.querySelector("#serverDI").getAttribute("data-DIContracts"))
    End With 
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(json(1).keys) + 1) = json(1).keys
        For i = 1 To json.Count
            .Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(json(i).keys) + 1) = json(i).Items
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another approach you may give a try. I used selectors within the script to shake off verbosity.

```
Sub FetchTabularContent()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim I&, C&, N&, R&

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/ferramentas/contratos-di-futuro"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document

        With Html.querySelectorAll("table tr")
            For N = 1 To .Length - 1
                With .item(N).querySelectorAll("th,td")
                    For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                        C = C + 1: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(R + 1, C) = .item(I).innerText
                    Next I
                    C = 0: R = R + 1
                End With
            Next N
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add before execution:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```